# Mehrere Adjektive vor einem Wort: alle im Dativ?

Tags: dative, genitive

Wenn ich einen Satz der folgenden Art habe ...

> Ein einstöckiger Steinbau mit angrenzendem, **rechteckigem/rechteckigen** Turm.

... werden dann die an zweiter und späteren Stellen gelisteten Adjektive im Dativ oder im Genitiv verwendet?

Comment: Wo genau vermutest du einen Genitiv?

Comment: wäre “rechteckigen“ nicht Genitiv? Ich hab keine Ahnung mehr von dem Zeug. :/ Üblicherweise kann ich daran, wie es sich anhört, beurteilen ob ein Satz stimmt oder nicht ^^

Comment: "rechteckigen" wäre schwache Deklination, was aber falsch ist. Da kein Artikel oder Demonstativ vorhanden ist, müssen alle Artikel stark dekliniert sein, also mit "-em".

Comment: Parallele Adjektive werden immer parallel gebeugt: Mit grosse*m*, todesverachtende*m* Einsatz. Verwirrung stiftet bei vielen Lernern, dass der *bestimmte Artikel* die Endung des folgenden Adjektivs beeinflusst: Mit de*m* grosse*n* Einsatz. Das gilt aber *nur* für den vorausgehenden Artikel, nicht für vorausgehende Adjektive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

»Bildet das zweite Adjektiv mit dem Substantiv eine Bedeutungseinheit, die als Ganzes vom ersten Adjektiv modifiziert wird, dann tritt Wechselflexion ein. […]: nach heftigem parlamentarischen Streit; mit hellem elektrischen Licht. Sind beide Adjektive dem Substantiv gegenüber nebengeordnet, tritt in der Regel Parallelflexion ein: nach langem heftigem Streit, mit hellem hartem Licht.«

Beim Beispielsatz "Ein einstöckiger Steinbau mit angrenzendem, rechteckigem/rechteckigen Turm." plädiere ich für Parallelflexion (rechteckigem), man kann das aber durchaus auch anders sehen.

Comment: Sollte im zweiten Fall nicht ein Komma zwischen den Adjektiven stehen?

Answer (score 2):

Für jedes einzelne Adjektiv gilt an dieser Stelle die gleiche Regel. Ein Adjektiv nimmt immer den Fall seines Substantivs an. Es werden also alle Adjektive im Beispiel im Dativ geschrieben. Die korrekte Endung von Adjektiven weicht im Dativ jedoch von der Endung des Substantiv ab: eine**m** angrenzende**n** Turm

Gemäß des Beispiels ist also folgende Formulierung korrekt:

> Ein einstöckiger Steinbau mit einem angrenzenden, rechteckigen Turm.

Comment: Der Beispielsatz des OP lässt aber den Artikel bei "Turm" weg.

Comment: Guest, would you like to expand your answer and add the variant without the article: "Ein einstöckiger Steinbau mit angrenzende**m**, rechteckige**m** Turm" ?

Comment: Ich befürchte, dass die Antwort so, wie sie ist, nur zu einer anderen Frage passt.